# Crashing on `func unsubscribe(_ key: DisposeKey)` of `ReplaySubject` in `RxSwift`?

Tags: rx-swift, replaysubject

Everything goes well on my framework demo util I vendored my framework to our app project which is big, the`unsubscribe:_` method that I mentioned in title was called. I searched the whole `RxSwift` source code and I found that method is not called anywhere, which was wired.The back trace is shown as below:

[image: 1]

[image: 1]

What's even stranger is when I rename that `unsubscribe` method, it was still called and `abstract method calling fatalError`.

My subject is defined as:

```
private let funcListPipe = ReplaySubject<[FuncItem]?>.create(bufferSize: 1)
```

And crashing when I send a next element through it:

```
funcListPipe.onNext(nil)
```

Comment: Sorry, but we are going to need more than the little bit you have shown...

Comment: @DanielT Sorry, as I mentioned our app project is so big for me to provide, and I can not reproduce that on my demo. I'll try to reproduce that later. But do you have any ideas what could be the reasons for that strange behavior.

Comment: How about at least providing all of the stack trace? Three lines isn't much to go on.

Comment: Try deleting the unsubscribe method. It isn't used anywhere so should be safe to delete.

Comment: @DanielT. Actually, I tried that before, deleting the unsubscribe method does work. I just want to know why that strange behavior happened, and what that method exists for? Our app integrates RxSwift as a pod. Deleting that method is a bit bothering.

Comment: I submitted a PR to remove it.

Comment: PR accepted. The next update will likely not have the method.